# How do I activate a scroll?

Tags: king-arthurs-gold

Is it a button? Do I have to be a specific class?

I know how to put it in my inventory or hold it out in front of me (`c`) and even how to store it in a Hall or Crate but not how to actually activate the thing.

For example, a scroll for a Drill in Take the Halls can be bought from the old man's store with some gold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press E and click the activate button which shows up while holding it. If this doesn't work then you are victim of a bug and you must rejoin the server.